# Facebook Graph Api: get all ursers tagged in a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling with Facebook Graph APIs: I'm trying to get all the people tagged in a photo but I only get myself as user tagged (also if there are more users tagged in the photo).

Is there any way to get all people tagged in a photo by Graph API?

Thanks
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way - only users who authorized your App too would show up. If a user did not authorize your App, he will not show up anywhere in any API call, for privacy reasons.

Comment: ok thx. The point is that all the other pepple tagged in the photo had authorized the app. And I still just get my info when I call the API to get user tagged in. Morevoer in the page of graph api: "If you read this edge with a User access token, only the current user is returned"